# Can I show base class properties in the Visual Studio watch window without them being hidden away under a submenu?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

If I have an object of a derived class in the Visual Studio watch window, its base class properties are hidden away under a "base" submenu. Is there any way to show all properties, even base class properties, in the main list, so I don't have to keep clicking "base"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.
2 methods that works for me (in VS 2012):

1. In the watch window, go to the base record, right click it and select `Add watch`.
2. Add to the watch window a record of: `derivedInstance as BasType`

Comment: Wouldn't that hide the derived class properties, though?

Comment: @ekolis Yes it will. You can open to records, 1 for derived and 1 for base.

Comment: Actually I tried this just now and discovered that (at least in VS2013, when I do .Cast<BaseType>() on an IEnumerable of the derived type) I get a sub-entry for the derived type on each object :)